# spring java - reuse tiles

Tags: spring, tiles

i have a j2ee written with spring framework and we are using tiles for templating.

overtime, developers have created numerous css styles and reuse them all over the jsp pages. for example we created a `<table class="tablestyle blue ">`, or `<select class="style1 style2 style3">` and it is used in multiple pages. the problem i faced is that whenever we create a new table/select, we have to ensure we key in the correct css styles and this is cumbersome.

my question is, is it possible to put this `<table>` and `<select>` with its css class styles into a template and reuse it in other templates?

Comment: make a separate tile for table and select, then make a separate tile for importing the css ex in this page you only need page.css,jquery-ui.css and on the other page just page.css.

Comment: how do you do it? for example in a table, how am i suppose to display the data? some tables have 2 roles with 2 td while others have more.

Answer (score 0):

you can have this kind of tile for example it is the `table`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <c:foreach items="${tableColumn}" var="column">
      <td><c:out value="${column}"/>
    </c:foreach>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

from the controller you will just put an column attribute to make it more flexible

and the `select` is all the same right?

```
<select>
   <c:foreach items="${optionItems}" var="option">
     <option><c:out value="${option}"/></option>
   </c:foreach>
</select>
```

in this case you could reuse the table and option tile in every jsp you want it.